# How can I create arbitrary amounts of enum values useable as flags in methods

Tags: c#, enums, bit

I am currently designing a permission structure. I'd really like to make the code as readable as possible. So, my `Account` class should have a `HasPermission` method that will check if it has a certain set of permissions. For them, I created an `enum`:

```
enum Permission {
    ACCESS,
    READ,
    WRITE
}
```

Now, the `HasPermission` methods signature currently looks like this:

```
public bool HasPermission(Permission perm_)
```

So if I want to check for multiple permissions, I have to do something like this:

```
if (acc.HasPermission(Permission.ACCESS) && acc.HasPermission(Permission.READ))
```

What do I need to do in order to be able to write this like

```
if (acc.HasPermission(Permission.ACCESS & Permission.READ))
```

Which I find much more easy to read and to understand. The key here is, that there are about 30 to 40 different permissions that I have to check in sometimes very weird combinations, so I can't really make up the bit-order myself, can I?

For example, I should also be able to check things like:

```
if (acc.HasPermission(Permission.ACCESS & Permission.READ
    & !(Permission.ONLY_X | Permission.ONLY_Y & Permissions.MUST_BE_Z))
```

How can I make this work with an arbitrary amount of enum values?

Comment: why don't you go with switch case if you have many condition

Comment: @DhavalPatel Because most of the time it's just one `if` but with a strange and often complex permission structure. I don't need different cases for different permissions, I just need to check if the account has the defined permissions and that's it.

Comment: Since you sample enum is not `[flags]` it is somewhat hard... Normally one would `value & (Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag5) == (Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag5)` to check for presence of all bits. Or if your `Permissions` would be simple class/struct instead of enum you could use custom `&` to combine them together in some sort of list...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The enum can be changed. What does `[Flag]` do exactly?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+flagsattribute ... It does not "do" anything, but shows that you intend to use values as bit flags and likely provided proper values that can be reasonably combined with `|` / `&` (usually powers of 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
using System;

namespace HasAccess
{
    [Flags]
    enum Permission
    {
        ACCESS = 1,
        READ = 2,
        WRITE = 4
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var permissons = Permission.ACCESS | Permission.READ;

            Console.WriteLine(permissons.HasFlag(Permission.ACCESS | Permission.READ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would include me creating bit-flags for every `Permission` value, right? Will that even be feasible with having over 40 permissions + the option of more in later patches?

Comment: No, not that many, you need something else to solve this problem than enums.

Comment: For 40 different permission it's not feasible, then you need you own abstraction.

Comment: Alright, I thought as much. Thanks for the information anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by using the `Flags` attribute on your enumeration and assign a value to the members in powers of 2:

```
[Flags]
enum Permission {
    ACCESS = 1,
    READ = 2,
    WRITE = 4
}
```

You can use flags enums just as other enums:

```
Permission permission = Permission.ACCESS;
```

Now let's say you want to add the `READ` permission to this value:

```
permission |= Permission.READ;
```

This will OR the current value of `permission` with the value you want to add, effectively adding it.

Or maybe you want to remove a permission:

```
permission &= ~Permission.READ;
```

This will AND permission with the bitwise complement of the value you want to remove, effectively removing it.

You can check if a permission contains a certain value, regardless any other values it may have:

```
if ((permission & Permission.ACCESS) == Permission.ACCESS)
{
    // permission has at least Permission.ACCESS set, but may have others set as well
}
```

Or you can check if a permission has multiple values you specify:

```
if ((permission & (Permission.ACCESS | Permission.READ)) == (Permission.ACCESS | Permission.READ))
{
    // Only true if permission has at least both ACCESS and READ 
}
```

Edit to add:

As per the comment, you can declare the enum to be of int64 type:

```
[Flags]
enum Permission : Int64
{
    ACCESS = 1 << 0,
    READ = 1 << 1,
    WRITE = 1 << 2
}
```

This will allow for 64 values to be used. The notation for the values, i.e. `1 << 0, 1<< 1` is easier to read and you can easily count how many values you have, and also prevents errors in assigning the larger values.

Comment: This will not work, because I have over 32 Permissions which will produce an overflow in the bits.

Comment: Well, technically you can have up to 64 values if you'd like, by using the `int64` datatype for the enum and starting at 0. I've edited my answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a class hierarchy with operator overloading so that you can create objects and combine them. It would be *slightly* less readable than your examples, but feasible.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
void Main()
{
    var permissions = new[] { "READ", "WRITE", "OPERATOR" };
    var check =
        new NamedPermission("READ")
        & new NamedPermission("WRITE")
        & !new NamedPermission("OPERATOR");

    check.ToString().Dump();
    check.HasPermission(permissions).Dump();
}

public abstract class Permission
{
    public abstract bool HasPermission(IEnumerable<string> userPermissions);

    public static AndPermission operator &(Permission leftOperand, Permission rightOperand)
    {
        return new AndPermission(leftOperand, rightOperand);
    }

    public static OrPermission operator |(Permission leftOperand, Permission rightOperand)
    {
        return new OrPermission(leftOperand, rightOperand);
    }

    public static NotPermission operator !(Permission operand)
    {
        return new NotPermission(operand);
    }
}

public class NamedPermission : Permission
{
    public NamedPermission(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override bool HasPermission(IEnumerable<string> userPermissions)
    {
        return userPermissions.Contains(Name);
    }

    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}

public abstract class BinaryPermissionOperator : Permission
{
    public BinaryPermissionOperator(Permission leftOperand, Permission rightOperand)
    {
        LeftOperand = leftOperand;
        RightOperand = rightOperand;
    }

    public Permission LeftOperand { get; private set; }
    public Permission RightOperand { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class UnaryPermissionOperator : Permission
{
    public UnaryPermissionOperator(Permission operand)
    {
        Operand = operand;
    }

    public Permission Operand { get; private set; }
}

public class AndPermission : BinaryPermissionOperator
{
    public AndPermission(Permission leftOperand, Permission rightOperand)
        : base(leftOperand, rightOperand)
    {
    }

    public override bool HasPermission(IEnumerable<string> userPermissions)
    {
        return LeftOperand.HasPermission(userPermissions)
            && RightOperand.HasPermission(userPermissions);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} && {1}", LeftOperand, RightOperand);
    }
}

public class OrPermission : BinaryPermissionOperator
{
    public OrPermission(Permission leftOperand, Permission rightOperand)
        : base(leftOperand, rightOperand)
    {
    }

    public override bool HasPermission(IEnumerable<string> userPermissions)
    {
        return LeftOperand.HasPermission(userPermissions)
            || RightOperand.HasPermission(userPermissions);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} || {1}", LeftOperand, RightOperand);
    }
}

public class NotPermission : UnaryPermissionOperator
{
    public NotPermission(Permission operand)
        : base(operand)
    {
    }

    public override bool HasPermission(IEnumerable<string> userPermissions)
    {
        return !Operand.HasPermission(userPermissions);
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("!{0}", Operand);
    }
}
```